# Is it ethical to put a surveillance camera inside a lab

Tags: ethics, audio-video-recording, lab-management, management

The Lab leader is putting a surveillance camera inside the lab to protect some precious devices bought recently. The viewpoint of the camera covers most of the lab and shows clearly the lab members 24h per day and 7 days a week. The camera is only accessed by the lab leader.

is it ethical to put such a camera inside the lab?

Comment: The answer depends on many factors wihch should be added. E.g. jurisdiction, whether the data is recorded, if yes if there are rules for deletion, if non-employees are present, ...

Comment: @OBu, certainly the _legality_ depends on those things.

Comment: You should also have a look at the legal side of this question. However, this depends strongly at the country in which you are in. Could you please specify this further?

Answer (score 10):

This largely depends on **disclosure** --- in cases where you record employees at work there are ethical and legal obligations relating to notification and disclosure.  The legal rules depend on your jurisdiction, but in most jurisdictions this situation is regulated by some kind of legislation on surveillance.  (E.g., in NSW in Australia this would be regulated by the *Workplace Surveillance Act 2005*.)  To check on the legality of this practice you should consult relevant surveillance legislation in your jurisdiction.  Regardless, your lab leader should certainly **contact the university legal counsel** before installing a surveillance camera.

As to the broader ethical question of surveillance (as opposed to its legality), there is a reasonable literature on this question in the business ethics journals (see e.g., [Ottensmeyer and Heroux 1991](https://www.jstor.org/stable/25072180), [Fairweather 1999](https://www.jstor.org/stable/25074188), [Halpern, Reville and Grunewald 2008](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/25482135), and [Hadjimatheou 2014](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24478571)).  I will not attempt to paraphrase this issue here since it is a large issue which is best understood by reference to the literature.

Comment: Thanks for your post. Which of the four references you indicate, would you counsel to read first as an introduction to the subject? (Yes, time constraints...)

Comment: Halpern et al (2008) is most directly associated with your question, so I'd start with that.

Comment: (I am not the OP, but thanks all the same.)

Comment: Oops: "Download ($43.95)"... Fortunately: http://www.whatthelawprofessorsaid.com/files/2941320/ArticleByHalpernRevilleGrunewaldJofBusEthics2008June.pdf

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is certainly ethical, so long as everyone knows it is there. It doesn't even necessarily show lack of trust in the regular lab denizens. An alternative, of course, would be to pay someone, a guard, to be always present.

I suppose it is possible that the leader's motives go beyond protecting the equipment, of course, but even that isn't problematic if a record of lab activities might be needed to assure against possible bad behavior, such as, for example harassment. In some situations the lab work may be so sensitive that a record needs to be kept.

As noted in comments on this page, the legality may be in question. But that varies from place to place.

To make it even clearer, if the camera is put in place without the knowledge of the participants it would be unethical. If the camera were put into a public area then it would also be unethical in the absence of come compelling reason that would mitigate it.

If the camera were put in place to monitor the people and their performance, rather than protect equipment, the situation becomes more difficult to asses. But it would probably be *unwise* to do it, whether ethical or not, because of the strong negative reaction that it would cause and which is evidenced in the comments here.

The ethical judgment I made is, therefore, very limited to a particular set of conditions as expressed in the question asked.

Comment: It should be noted that - whether you think it's ethical or not - video surveillance of your employees may be illegal depending on jurisdiction. In the described case for example I'm fairly certain that it would be illegal in Germany.

Comment: Thanks.  with the widespread use of the surveillance camera I think this subject should be treated well so that employee know their rights.

Comment: Sorry but "ethical, [as] long as everyone knows it is there" is an extremely short-sighted approach of the question.

Comment: @Did, sorry, I don't understand. Spying isn't ethical, generally speaking. Observing is a different issue.

Comment: You don't really explain why you think it's appropriate to use camera surveillance in the lab; you just claim it is, period. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Your argument seems to be that, if the "observed" people know they are "observed", then it is ethical to observe them. Sorry but, to me, this is a fallacy. Let us imagine a situation such that we cross every morning in the street. On day D-1, I calmly explain to you that the next day, when we shall cross, I will punch you in the face. Do you think the cops would dismiss your complaint if, on day D, we do cross as usual and I do punch you in the face? After all, I warned you, so my ethics, if I understand your logic, is impeccable...

Comment: I think it is fine as long as people know it is there. Similarly nothing wrong with screening researchers coming out of weapons grade facilities in Los Alamos to prevent plutonium theft.  Just part of doing business.

Comment: @Did, your analogy and your reasoning are flawed.

Comment: Glad to know. Care to explain how they are?

Comment: @Did Seems obvious to me: Permission to punch was never granted.

Comment: @user2768 By that logic, you would also require permission to surveil in the original scenario, not just give acknowledgement of the surveillance.

Comment: Folks, I think what @Did is saying is that, while it may or may not be ethical to install surveillance cameras in the lab, the explanation “the employees were informed” is not sufficient, just like saying “I informed you that I was going to punch you in the face” is not sufficient to make the action ethical. So it is the _reasoning_ that is flawed (as the analogy illustrates quite well IMO), while the _conclusion_ itself may still end up being correct, but for a more complicated/subtle (or entirely different) reason than that offered. (@Did, hope that’s consistent with what you wanted to say)

Comment: @DanRomik, I wasn't giving a _reason_ why it was ethical. I was giving a binary condition. If you install it without informing everyone then it is unethical.

Comment: Moreover, a lab is not a public space. The answer would not be the same if the discussion were about public spaces. Nor was the question asked about surveillance _of the people_, or monitoring job performance and behavior,  but protection of the equipment in a place where non-authorized people might appear.

Answer (score 4):

If the lab ever uses human subjects, it's important to keep this camera in mind as a potential breach of confidentiality. Most IRBs would (a) want to know that subjects are being recorded, (b) want the camera mentioned in the consent form, and (c) want a plan for the storage and disposal of recordings that include subjects.